# Descriptors as instance attributes in python

Tags: python, descriptor

To the question:

> Why can't descriptors be instance attributes?

it has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954331/dynamically-adding-property-in-python) that:

> descriptor objects needs to live in the class, not in the instance

because that is the way that the `__getattribute__` is implemented.

A simple example. Consider a descriptor:

```
class Prop(object):

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return obj._value * obj._multiplier

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        obj._value = value

class Obj(object):

    val = Prop()

    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 1
        self._multiplier = 0
```

Consider the case in which each obj has multiple Prop: I would need to use unique names to identify the values and multipliers (Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954331/dynamically-adding-property-in-python). Having a per instance descriptor object would allow to store the `_multiplier` (and the `_value`) in the descriptor itself, simplifying a few things.

To implement per instance descriptor attributes you need to either:

1. create a per instance class [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954331/dynamically-adding-property-in-python)
2. override `__getattribute__` [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232174/can-a-python-descriptor-be-used-to-instantiate-an-attribute-in-the-init-of-a)

I am aware that similar questions have been raised before, but I have not found a real explanation:

1. Why Python is designed this way?
2. What is the suggested way to store information that the descriptor needs but is per instance?

Comment: Just FYI, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#:~:text=Descriptors%20only%20work%20when%20used%20as%20class%20variables.%20When%20put%20in%20instances%2C%20they%20have%20no%20effect.) it is clearly mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Plenty of advanced functionality only works when defined on a class rather than an instance; all of the special methods, for example.  As well as making code evaluation more efficient, this makes clear the separation between instances and types which otherwise would tend to collapse (because of course all types are objects).

I'm not sure how recommended this is, but you could in the instance store a mapping from descriptor instance to attribute value:

```
class Prop(object):
     def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return obj._value * obj._multiplier[self]

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        obj._value = value

class Obj(object):
    val = Prop()

    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 1
        self._multiplier = {Obj.val: 0}
```

This has obvious advantages over the other two suggested options:

1. per-instance classes break object orientation and increase memory usage;
2. overriding `__getattribute__` is inefficient (as all attribute access must go through the overridden special method) and is fragile.

---

As an alternative, you could use a proxy property:

```
class PerInstancePropertyProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return instance.__dict__[self.prop].__get__(instance, owner)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.prop].__set__(instance, value)
class Prop(object):
    def __init__(self, value, multiplier):
        self.value = value
        self.multiplier = multiplier
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self.value * self.multiplier
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = value
class Obj(object):
    val = PerInstancePropertyProxy('val')
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__['val'] = Prop(1.0, 10.0)
    def prop(self, attr_name):
        return self.__dict__[attr_name]
```

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by **break object orientation**. Second, the problem that I see with this approach is how to provide a simple API to change the multiplier. Users will have to do something like `obj._multiplier[Obj.val] = 10`. This can be wrapped in a function `def change_multiplier(self, attr_name, new_value)` but does not scale nicely if `Prop` has multiple attributes. Something like `def prop(self, attr_name): return self.__dict__[attr_name]` could be used to do something like `obj.prop('val').multiplier = 10`.

Comment: @Hernan there's a usual assumption that instances have the same type; violate that and various things will break.  As far as changing the multiplier goes, perhaps a proxy property? - see edit above.

Comment: Is true that all instances will not be of the same type, but you might make subclasses so isinstance will still work. Regarding the proxy, I wrote something like this but I am not sure that is a good idea. Basically, `obj.prop('val')` returns a proxy object that knows about `obj` and `val`. When you do `obj.prop('val').multiplier = 10` it writes to `obj._multiplier[val] = 10`. I am just not sure how maintainable it will be.

Answer (score 18):

This exact question was [raised on Python-list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-January/618570.html) earlier this year. I'm just going to quote [Ian G. Kelly's response](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-January/618572.html):

> The behavior is by design.  First, keeping object behavior in the
>   class definition simplifies the implementation and also makes instance
>   checks more meaningful.  To borrow your Register example, if the "M"
>   descriptor is defined by some instances rather than by the class, then
>   knowing that the object "reg" is an instance of Register does not tell
>   me anything about whether "reg.M" is a valid attribute or an error. As
>   a result, I'll need to guard virtually every access of "reg.M" with a
>   try-except construct just in case "reg" is the wrong kind of register.
>
> Second, the separation of class from instance also helps you keep
>   object behavior separate from object data.  Consider the following
>   class:
>
> ```
> class ObjectHolder(object):
>     def __init__(self, obj):
>         self.obj = obj
> ```
>
> Don't worry about what this class might be useful for.  Just know that
>   it's meant to hold and provide unrestricted access to arbitrary Python
>   objects:
>
> ```
> >>> holder = ObjectHolder(42)
> >>> print(holder.obj) 42
> >>> holder.obj = range(5)
> >>> print(holder.obj) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> ```
>
> Since the class is meant to hold arbitrary objects, it's even valid
>   that somebody might want to store a descriptor object there:
>
> ```
> >>> holder.obj = property(lambda x: x.foo)
> >>> print(holder.obj) <property object at 0x02415AE0>
> ```
>
> Now suppose that Python invoked the descriptor protocol for
>   descriptors stored in instance attributes:
>
> ```
> >>> holder = ObjectHolder(None)
> >>> holder.obj = property(lambda x: x.foo)
> >>> print(holder.obj)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: 'ObjectHolder' object has no attribute 'foo'
> ```
>
> In this case, the ObjectHolder would fail to simply hold the property
>   object as data.  The mere act of assigning the property object, a
>   descriptor, to an instance attribute would *change the behavior* of
>   the ObjectHolder.  Instead of treating "holder.obj" as a simple data
>   attribute, it would start invoking the descriptor protocol on accesses
>   to "holder.obj" and ultimately redirect them to the non-existent and
>   meaningless "holder.foo" attribute, which is certainly not what the
>   author of the class intended.

If you want to be able to support multiple instances of a descriptor, just make that descriptor's constructor take a name argument (prefix), and prefix the added attributes with that name. You could even create a namespace object (dictionary) within the class instance to hold all of the new property instances.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.6 this can be done quite easily. Maybe it's not as intended but hey, if it works, right? ;)

[Python 3.6 adds the `__set_name__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#object.__set_name__):

> `object.__set_name__(self, owner, name)`
>
> Called at the time the owning class owner is created. The descriptor has been assigned to name.
>
> New in version 3.6.

Using this name to store the internal value in the instance's dict seems to work fine.

```
>>> class Prop:
...     def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
...         print('get')
...         return instance.__dict__.setdefault(self.name, None)
...     def __set__(self, instance, value):
...         print('set')
...         instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
... 
>>> class A:
...     prop = Prop()
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.prop = 'spam'
set
>>> a.prop
get
'spam'
```

Note that this is not a full descriptor implementation and of course if you decide to use it it's at your own risk.

Comment: **Question:** What do you mean by *this is not a full descriptor implementation*? To  my knowledge, it is a perfectly applicable example of a descriptor.

Comment: `instance.__dict__` – what about classes with `__slots__`?