# Python - How to pass instance variable value to descriptor parameter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-descriptors

Considering below case,

**ItemList Class:**

```
# filename: item_list.py

# locators dictionary is intentionally placed outside `ItemList` class
locators = {
    'item_id': 'css=tr:nth-of-type({item_num}) .id',
    'item_title': 'css=tr:nth-of-type({item_num}) .alert-rules',
    # other properties
}

class ItemList(Item):
    # --- these are data descriptors ---
    # getting item_id value based on its item_num
    item_id = TextReadOnly(locators['item_id'].format(item_num=self.item_num))

    # getting item_title value based on its item_num
    item_title = TextReadOnly(locators['item_title'].format(item_num=self.item_num))


    def __init__(self, context, item_num=0):
        # self.item_num can't be passed to locators
        self.item_num = item_num

        super(ItemList, self).__init__(
            context
        )
```

In this case, I want to pass `self.item_num` value to `item_num` inside locators dictionary in `ItemList` class.

The reason is I want each of `item_id` and `item_title` refers to particular `item_num`.

I'm stuck on this part :

```
item_id = TextReadOnly(locators['item_id'].format(item_num=self.item_num))
item_title = TextReadOnly(locators['item_title'].format(item_num=self.item_num))
```

`self.item_num` value can't be passed to locators when instance is already made.

**Implementation:**

```
# filename: test.py

# print item_id values from item_num=1
item_1 = ItemList(context, 1)
print (‘Item_id_1: ’ + item_1.id)

# print item_id values from item_num=2
item_2 = ItemList(context, 2)
print (‘Item_id_2: ’ + item_2.id)

# ^ no result produced from item_1.id and item_2.id because self.item_num value can't be passed to locators
```

Is it possible to update data descriptor from instance variable?

How to pass instance variable value to data descriptor parameter?

---

**Additional info:**

I tried to call `item_id` and `item_title` as instance attribute but no luck. I noticed that data descriptor can’t be instance attribute from this post: [Data descriptor should be a class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599972/descriptors-as-instance-attributes-in-python)

Item Class:

```
# filename: item.py

import abc


class Item(Page):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.__context = context
        super(Item, self).__init__(
            self.__context.browser
        )
```

Descriptor:

```
# filename: text_read_only.py

class TextReadOnly(object):
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.__locator = locator

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        try:
            e = instance.find_element_by_locator(self.__locator)
        except AttributeError:
            e = instance.browser.find_element_by_locator(self.__locator)

        return e.text

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        pass
```

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong - the class attributes can't depend on instance attributes, as the class is initialized first.  If you want `item_id` and `item_title` to vary per instance, why make them class attributes in the first place?

Comment: Hello @domoarrigato: I make `item_id` and `item_title` as class attributes because I want to use descriptor **TextReadOnly**. I noticed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599972/descriptors-as-instance-attributes-in-python) that data descriptor should be a class attribute. Is there another approach to implement it?

Comment: If you want to keep them as class attributes, you can try to make them as "protected class properties", see [this][1] question to see how.

In your specific case I think this is overkill, `item_id` and `item_title` look more like Instance Descriptors than Data Descriptors, so I'll make them as instance attributes.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189699/how-to-make-a-class-property

Comment: Hrabal and Domoarrigato:
Thanks for both your answers. Those helped me to dig deeper about the concept of descriptor and instance attribute. I'll post the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](http://blog.brianbeck.com/post/74086029/instance-descriptors) and came up with solution to add the descriptors to an object.

This solution below worked for me:

1. Add `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` into **Item Class**

   ```
   # filename: item.py

   import abc


   class Item(Page):
       __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

       def __init__(self, context):
           self.__context = context
           super(Item, self).__init__(
               self.__context.browser
           )

       def __getattribute__(self, name):
           value = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
           if hasattr(value, '__get__'):
               value = value.__get__(self, self.__class__)
           return value

       def __setattr__(self, name, value):
           try:
               obj = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
           except AttributeError:
               pass
           else:
               if hasattr(obj, '__set__'):
                   return obj.__set__(self, value)
           return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   ```
2. Move class attribute to instance attribute in **ItemList** constructor

   ```
   # filename: item_list.py

   # locators dictionary is intentionally placed outside `ItemList` class
   locators = {
       'item_id': 'css=tr:nth-of-type({item_num}) .id',
       'item_title': 'css=tr:nth-of-type({item_num}) .alert-rules',
       # other properties
   }


   class ItemList(Item):
       def __init__(self, context, item_num=0):
           self.item_num = item_num
           # self.item_num is able to be passed to locators
           self.item_id = TextReadOnly(locators['item_id'].format(item_num=self.item_num))
           self.item_title = TextReadOnly(locators['item_title'].format(item_num=self.item_num))

           super(ItemList, self).__init__(
               context
           )
   ```