# Python: How to access instance attributes in nested descriptors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, lazy-evaluation, python-descriptors

### Example

Take the following example

```
class Leaf:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        # TODO How to access Root.value here?


class Branch:
    bar = Leaf()


class Root:
    foo = Branch()

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Root(20)
    y = Root(30)

    print(x.foo.bar)  # 20

    a = x.foo

    print(a.bar)  # 20
    print(y.foo.bar)  # 30
    print(a.bar)  # 20
```

In `Leaf.__get__` `instance` points to the `Branch` instance. However, I need to access `value`, which is an instance member of `Root`.

### Background

My task is to write a parser for a large file header. The parser shall be robust and fast. Therefore, instead of parsing the whole header structure, I proposed to use descriptors to lazy parse the fields. This allows for decoding/encoding the header fields only when required.
So, there's a root object that holds the complete header as a bytearray and when a field is accessed, its descriptor reads from or writes to this bytearray. However, the header structure is hierarchical and contains nested fields. For that reason I need to access the roots bytearray from a nested descriptor.

### Related questions and solutions

Similar questions about instance descriptors have been raised before.

**1. Create a per instance**

The solution would be to add the descriptors to the instances instead of classes and set the shared value as reference. IMO this seems a bit inefficient.

See [Dynamically adding @property in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954331/dynamically-adding-property-in-python) and [Python - How to pass instance variable value to descriptor parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977559/python-how-to-pass-instance-variable-value-to-descriptor-parameter)

**2. Override `__getattribute__`**

I don't think this would work, since `__getattribute__` of `Branch` doesn't know about the `Root` instance.

**3. Propagate `value`**

While traversing the structure, `Branch.__get__` gets called, where we could store a reference to the root instance, which is accessible from `Leaf.__get__`. However, this will not work if we mix up calls on multiple instances of `Root`.

---

Finally, my question is if there are better solutions for this specific problem?

Comment: Do you need `Branch` and `Leaf` instances to be class variables in `Root` and `Branch` classes respectively?

Comment: Listed as the first solution in _Related questions_ it might be a solution to use instance descriptors instead of class descriptors. However, I think this would increase the memory footprint a lot, since for every instance of `Root` a bunch of `Branch`es and `Leaf`s need to be duplicated.

Comment: I don't think you can do it given the constraints without involving some traceback magic to get the root instance from parent frames. I would suggest not using nested descriptors if memory is such a big concern, but implementing the logic in `Branch` (you can use `__getattr__` for evaluating missing values).